# EF Core: Delete record from generated cross record table on SQL Server side?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

So when I have two entities:

```
public class User {
    ....

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role {
    ....

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then EF Core will generate three tables:

- User
- Role
- UserRole

And when I want to add something to cross record table I can just get the user and add it to the ICollection and save, like below:

```
var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
user.Roles.Add(myRole);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

But how do I delete a record from this cross record table? Because when I get the role for example, and I want to delete a specific user (from the role side) it won't include the `Users` collection automatically. I want to not force an include because there might be thousands of users to my role.

```
var role = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "MyRole");
role.Users.Remove(myUser);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

the `role.Users` is empty because I didn't include `.Include(i => i.Users)`. And I don't want my C# to process this. So how do I let SQL Server handle the deletion properly?

---

### EDIT 1

Because the cross record table is "virtual" my application context doesn't have a direct reference to it. I can't call `_context.UserRole...` because that isn't a `DbSet` that exists

Comment: can't you use removeall  `users.RemoveAll(x=>x.Roles.Any(y=>y.Name== "MyRole"))`

Comment: @coder_b If this works, you should add this as an answer! That would be definitely a very good one.

Comment: You could just fetch the user you want, including roles and remove the role from the user.

Comment: @coder_b don't think that would work because you are using the users `DbSet` to remove `Roles`.

Comment: not sure! you have user object which has is linked to roles collection, where we are getting  all users who has "MyRole". you could test,

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following ways to remove one many-to-many relationship:

### Include, maybe the other way around

Use `_context.Roles.Include(r => r.Users)` to get access to the list of users and remove the one for which you want to sever the link with roles.

Caveat: if there are a lot users, Include will load them all.

To tackle the performance issue, you can attack the problem the other way around `_context.Users.Include(r => r.Roles).First(u => u.UserId == yourSpecificId)` for instance, will load one user with all its roles, and usually you don't have thousands of roles.

That would be my preferred option.

### Explicitly define the relationship table

You can also explicitly create the `UserRole` join table as an entity, and add it to your context, to get an access to it as a dbset. Refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many), Many-to-Many section, scroll down until you see

> Note:
>
> The ability to configure many-to-many relationships was introduced in EF Core 5.0, for previous version use the following approach.

Actually, until EFCore 5 it seems to me that you *had* to have the join table as an entity to configure the proper many-to-many relationships. Only since the 5 version this table is handled implicitly for convenience.

Caveat: some "ugly" boilerplate code to add.

### Direct SQL command

EF has this flexibility, you can always run a specific SQL query to handle a particular scenario for which EF framework is not well suited.

```
string queryString = "DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE UserId = @UserId AND RoleId = @RoleId";
var sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]  
{  
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "RoleId", Value =  yourRoleId },
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "UserId", Value =  yourUserId },
}
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(queryString, sqlParams);
```

Caveat: maintenance / technical debt as you have hardcoded db table names and columns in your C# code.

You could also use a stored proc following the same approach, effectively shifting the technical debt from the C# code to the DB.

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question, the reason I don't want to include the users is because I don't want C# to have to worry about thousands of entities in the Users table if it does not have to. So does this impact performance, and if it does. Is there a smart way of handling this, maybe leaving the many-to-many table out of my context. This is really the origin of my question.

Comment: well, indeed, if you have many attached entities they will all be loaded, as far as I know. That's a valid concern. Now, maybe you can turn the query the other way around. It's more likely you don't have thousands of roles, so `_context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).Where(u => u.userId == yourId).First()` should load a specific user with all its roles, and then you can remove the role. Further optimization could be done with getting only a few columns and/or setting indexes.

Comment: Another option I haven't written yet is to execute a direct query to the db:   `string queryString = "DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE UserId = @UserId AND RoleId = @RoleId";` and define the corresponding params : `SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]  {  new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "RoleId", Value =  ... }, ...  };`
and then `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(queryString, sqlParams);`. This way you don't need the dbset UserRole in your code. Caveat is that it adds some manual maintenance / technical debt in case your db tables or columns are refactored.